# jquery $( document ).ready function stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, function

I have a `$( document ).ready(function()` in the `initialize()` function of a wordpress page this was working well until few days ago. Suddenly I find this is not working now with the help of fire bug.

I didn't make any changes to code other than doing minor upgrade to the WP template.

```
var found_record =0 ;
var lat_nearby = new Array();
var lon_nearby = new Array();
var loc_name_nearby = new Array();
var icon_type_nearby = new Array();
var post_id_nearby = new Array();
var in_list_nearby = new Array();
// some other parameters 

    function initialize() {
        genenrate_parameters();
        var mapProp = 
            {
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(lat1,lon1),
            zoom:zoom_level,
            mapTypeId:map_type
        };

        var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
        setMarkers(map);
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: "loading...",
                    maxWidth:"150"
        });
        //script below creates a SORTED list of sites near main site
        if(found_record==1) {
            var $ = jQuery;
            var max_records=50;     
            $( document ).ready(function() {
            //put the list to an array  
            var near_list = new Array(lat_nearby.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < lat_nearby.length; i++) {
                near_list[i] = new Array(7);
                near_list[i][0] = lat_nearby[i];
                near_list[i][1] = lon_nearby[i];
                near_list[i][2] = loc_name_nearby[i];
                near_list[i][3] = icon_type_nearby[i];
                near_list[i][4] = post_id_nearby[i];
                near_list[i][5] = gpsToKm (lat1,lon1,lat_nearby[i], lon_nearby[i]);
                near_list[i][6] = in_list_nearby[i];
                };
            // generate a html code block and populate pop_text parameter
            pop_text=pop_text+pop_text1+"</ul>\n";
            $( "#nearby-locations" ).append(pop_text);
            });     
        };  
    }

    function loadScript(){  
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAU5dPIpTlKWqHJndusLV1UsiXGQ4iz1v4&sensor=true&callback=initialize"; document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    window.onload = loadScript;
```

1. This was working code until few weeks ago. All the variables are defined and populated properly.
2. purpose of this code segment  is to populate the div id "nearby-locations" with the text in "pop_text" parameter.
3. when I debug the page with firebug , java script is executed uptp "$( document ).ready(function(){" and then moves to "};" (exit point of ready(function) ).
4. This probably means some return error code in jquery is exiting this function. This does not give a error but doesn't populate web page with the text segment which is dynamically created.

sample page is here

http://amazinglanka.com/wp/hakgala-strict-nature-reserve/

if some one can go through this and help me i would be really grateful

thanks

*** I have updated the question as per the requests of users but still this is not a fully functional code as the full code is lengthy with lot of other unrelated functionality. I am unable to change the live code to make the issue more prominent as this will break the full site

Unfortunately best ways to understand the issue to the load the given post in debugging mode.

Hope I have change to question to an acceptable level

Comment: Always post all of the relevant code and markup **in** the question, don't just link. Links rot, and separately people shouldn't have to leave the site to help you.

Comment: Your sample page is down

Comment: What error(s) do you get?

Comment: why do you put `doc ready` in `initialize()` func.

Comment: @putvande - may be the hosting had a issue. Its up and operating now, No erroers just skips the code segment

Comment: @Jai : Just to see if I can get an out put to debug. But the execution doesn't come up to that line.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
   //place your code here
   console.log( "document loaded and ready" );

   var near_list = new Array(lat_nearby.length);
   for (var i = 0; i < lat_nearby.length; i++) {
        //...
   }
});
```

You don't need to call `Initialize();`

Answer (score 0):

Well, one thing to note is if lat_nearby isn't defined (it isn't in the snippet you provided), execution will halt when you try to call the '.length' property in your Array declaration.

Comment: all variables are declared. there are no issues on this side. The script execution doest even come to this line.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of trouble shooting the issue has be isolated to an extent.

The issue was not in the script above but due to another plugin which also calls ( document ).ready(function() in jQuery. the ready function above was not firing due to a conflict with it.

the plugin has been disabled and the above script is working as expected. If there is any useful additional info will update here

Comment: That would be strange as `jQuery(document).ready` can be called multiple times and the actions will be chained, not overriden.